# Magento 1 to Magento 2 Data Migration Tool Error Remaining Time: < 1 sec In Mysql.php line 109: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento2.4.6, data-migration-tool

I'm migrating data from 1.9.4.3 to Magento 2.4.6 and ran into this error on data migration using the Magento Data Migration Tool for 2.4.6

```
[2023-11-26T17:04:40.663535+00:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started 0% [>---------------------------] Remaining Time: < 1 sec In Mysql.php line 109: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`ufgyswqjsd`. `catalog_compare_item`, CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_COMPARE_ITEM_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCE S `ufgyswqjsd`.`customer_entity` (`entity_id`)), query was: TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity` In Mysql.php line 90: SQLSTATE[
```